# how to remove the y-axis line and format the value of the y-axis in google column chart

Tags: javascript, charts, formatting, google-visualization

Im using google column chart in my application in my chart i need to remove the tiny space between my blue and grey bars and also to format the y axis values. Please suggest me, how to remove that tiny gap between them. My Chart [image]

Code for the chart

```
google.load("visualization", "1", {packages: ["columnchart"]});                
var datum=[];
                        datum=[[2,15,25]];
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([['column1', 'column2', 'column3']].concat(datum), false);
                            var options = {
                            legend: {position: 'none'},
                            colors: ['3399FF', 'C0C0C0'],
                            tooltip: {trigger: 'none'},
//                            vAxis: {minValue: 0, maxValue: maxValue, ticks: tick, format: '$'}
                            };
                                    var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart'));
                            chart.draw(data, options);
```

**Updated**

How to remove the yaxis line and need to format the y axis value like $10, $15, $30. Is there any way to do that in column chart package. The link i'have refered to do the chart is [this](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart_old)

Comment: There is no way to remove the gap between bars at the same axis value.

Comment: Looking at your data, did you intend to have two bars at the axis value `2`, or did you intend to have 3 bars with the values `2`, `15`, and `25`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, don't use the old version of the ColumnChart; it is deprecated and doesn't offer any features that the newer version doesn't also have.  Load it like this:

```
google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart']});
```

To format the axis values, you need to use the vAxis.format option:

```
var options = {
    legend: {position: 'none'},
    colors: ['3399FF', 'C0C0C0'],
    tooltip: {trigger: 'none'},
    vAxis: {
        format: '$#'
    }
};
```

Comment: but in this corechart package the gap between grey and blue bars is cant to remove

Comment: The gap exists in the "columnchart" package's ColumnCharts as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the following to your `options` object: `bar: {groupWidth: '100%'}`.

This will remove the gap between your gray and your blue bar.

All options are also listed in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart?hl=de&csw=1#Configuration_Options).